# Capifony can't download composer - not following redirect

Tags: symfony, composer-php, capifony

I'm using Capifony to deploy my Symfony2 application, but as of today it can't download composer - jenkins output:

```
[32m--> Downloading Composer[0m
* executing "sh -c 'cd /data/www/testing/s00110/releases/20150426161117 && curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php'"
servers: ["*domain*"]
[*domain*] executing command
** [out :: *domain*] <html>
** [out :: *domain*] <head><title>302 Found</title></head>
** [out :: *domain*] <body bgcolor="white">
** [out :: *domain*] <center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
** [out :: *domain*] <hr><center>nginx</center>
** [out :: *domain*] </body>
** [out :: *domain*] </html>
command finished in 46ms
```

It seems composer moved their installer to https and Capifony isn't following the redirect. Is there an option to tell capifony where to download composer from?

Comment: See this issue in the Capifony repository: https://github.com/everzet/capifony/issues/570 - they are working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new version of Capifony, [version 2.8.5](https://github.com/everzet/capifony/releases/tag/v2.8.5), has been released a couple of hours ago, which fixes this issue.

Updating to 2.8.5 should solve your problems with the Composer download.

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be an option to set the url, but you can add your own task. To circumvent capifony downloading from the wrong url I added:

```
task :download_composer do
  run "cd " + release_path + " && curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php"
end

before "symfony:composer:update", "download_composer"
before "symfony:composer:install", "download_composer"
```

This works because capifony checks if composer.phar is already present, if it is it'll warn you but just continue anyway

Answer (score 0):

Just update capifony to version 2.8.4.

Comment: Downvoted because the problem existed with 2.8.4, though I did not mention it in my original post - accepted the answer to update to 2.8.5 as this solves the issue